# How to return the elements in the odd position?

Tags: r

Say we have :

```
vector <- c(3:10)
```

I want to find the elements in vector in odd position, put all the elements in the even position to the end of `v`, with the order reversed.

so it would look like

result

```
3 5 7 9
```

result2

```
3 5 7 9 10 8 6 4
```

but I need a short function , and can't use loop

Comment: I don't understand- neither of the guys answered this question couldn't edit it too?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
vector <- 3:10
n <- length(vector)
c(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 1], rev(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 0]))
## [1]  3  5  7  9 10  8  6  4
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your most direct approach will be

```
vector <- 3:10

result <- vector[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
result2 <- c(vector[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rev(vector[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit faster:

```
n <- length(vector)/2
result <- vector[c(2*(1:n)-1,2*(n:1))]
```

Speed comparison:

```
vector <- 3:10

system.time(
  for ( i in 1:100000 )
  {
    n <- length(vector)/2
    result_A <- vector[c(2*(1:n)-1,2*(n:1))]
  }
)

system.time(
  for ( i in 1:100000 )
  {
    n <- length(vector)
    result_B <- c(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 1], rev(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 0]))
  }
)

system.time(
  for ( i in 1:100000 )
  {
    result_C <- c(vector[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rev(vector[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
  }
)
```

.

```
> vector <- 3:10

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:100000 )
+   {
+     n <- length(vector)/2
+     result_A <- vector[c(2*(1:n)-1,2*(n:1))]
+   }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.64    0.00    0.65 

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:100000 )
+   {
+     n <- length(vector)
+     result_B <- c(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 1], rev(vector[seq(n) %% 2 == 0]))
 .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
  10.78    0.00   10.86 

> system.time(
+   for ( i in 1:100000 )
+   {
+     result_C <- c(vector[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rev(vector[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
+   }
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
   2.81    0.00    2.83
```

.

```
> result_A
[1]  3  5  7  9 10  8  6  4
> result_B
[1]  3  5  7  9 10  8  6  4
> result_C
[1]  3  5  7  9 10  8  6  4
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c(seq(min(vector), max(vector), by=2), rev(vector[!vector %in% a]))

# [1]  3  5  7  9 10  8  6  4
```